# How do I move my cursor to an element in Dart?

Tags: cursor, element, target, dart

Just got started with dartlang and extended the project sample a little. It seems that the focus method on class Element does not work or maybe I'm not using it properly. Wanted to get a validation behaviour with "focus" on "error". Here's my code...

```
#import('dart:html');

num rotatePos = 0;

var nameField;

const DEFAULT_VALUE = "Click here!";

void main() {

  query("#text").text = DEFAULT_VALUE;

  query("#submit").on.click.add(rotateText);
}

void rotateText(Event event) {
  rotatePos += 360;

  nameField = query("#name");

  var textElement = query("#text");

  String insertedName = nameField.value;

  textElement.style.transition = "1s";
  textElement.style.transform = "rotate(${rotatePos}deg)";

  updateFromElement(textElement, insertedName);
}

void updateFromElement(Element textElement, String value) {

  Element errorField = query("#errorValue");

  if (value == "") {
    errorField.text = "Text Field is empty, please insert a value!";
    errorField.style.color = "red";
    textElement.text = DEFAULT_VALUE;
    textElement.focus();
  } else {
    textElement.text = value;
    errorField.text = "";
  }
}
```

Element.focus() seems not to work or maybe I'm missunderstanding something here. Also adding HTML file for better understanding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sandbox.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sandbox</h1>

    <p>Dart Sandbox</p>

    Enter any text: <input type="text" id="name"> <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"> <div id="error"><p id="errorValue"></div>

    <div id="container">
      <p id="text"></p>
    </div>

    <script type="application/dart" src="web/sandbox.dart"></script>
    <script src="http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried mocking up a sample of what you had. Adding a few components to the HTML to roughly create the same effect. I found your issue:

```
var textElement = query("#text");
// ....
updateFromElement(textElement, insertedName);
```

You're passing the textElement which is a `<P>` (paragraph) element. Not the text field. So you can't call focus() on it. Try this:

```
updateFromElement(nameField, insertedName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Matt B, I was able to see the error... I won't change the parameter like he suggested though. It's an ugly pattern anyway. But to make this work properly, just exchange following line:

- textElement.focus();
+ nameField.focus();

Also a better wording for the method would be "updateToElement(Element targetElement, String value)"

Comment: True, but with the sample code you have above, just making that change will not work as nameField will not be in that scope, since it is defined in the rotateText function not your updateFromElement. That said, merging that extra function with rotateText would be an appropriate approach and then making the changes you mention above. :)

Comment: of course, nameField is a "class member" like rotatePos and DEFAULT_VALUE... it's just assigned in rotateText. I can reference it in any void in the file scope. But I get your point, the whole design is not easy to understand from a dev POV...